# JMeter - How to pass all the HTTP Request of my group to an if controller

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter

I have a bunch of HTTP Requests inside my Threads group and I want all of them to be evaluated inside an IF Controller which has a specific condition.

[image]

JRS233 Listener contains this script:

```
if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
    vars.put('samplerFailed', 'true')
}

if(prev.isSuccessful()) {
    vars.put('samplerSuccess', 'true'); 
}
```

*if CONTROLLER OK* cointains this condition:

```
${samplerFailed}
```

and *if Controller KO* has this condition:

```
${samplerSuccess}
```

I want the two IF CONTROLLERS to be executed for all the samplers.

How can I achieve it?

thanks

Comment: What's inside the if? maybe it can be achieve without an If

Comment: there is an SMTP Sampler for sending an email

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JMeter sending email if one of the HTTP requests fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42782268/jmeter-sending-email-if-one-of-the-http-requests-fails)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) to your Test Plan (the same level as all the HTTP Request) and put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
       vars.put('samplerFailed', 'true')
   }
   ```
2. Change your If Controller condition to `${samplerFailed}`

This way If Controller's children will be executed only if there is any failure in the [samplers in scope of the JSR223 Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide).

Comment: do u mean without using a transaction controller?

Comment: It is not required for this setup

Comment: thanks Dmitri, it did not seem to work, please see my change

Answer (score 0):

You can [loop through different URLs/ HTTP Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755384/jmeter-loop-through-all-values-in-csv) and do same logic for each request.

Put HTTP request and If Controllers under While Controller and add CSV Data Set Config that will read your URLs from a file.

While loop will stop until finish reading CSV file using `${url}` condition

your flow will remain the same, the only different it will be executed per line in CSV file.